# Electric force at a distant point created by a changing current in a wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Regarding the following figure:

[image]

A text claims when the current **I** through the wire **|AB|** is increased it will set up an electric force **f** at a point **P**. And if there will be a wire **|A'B'|** there will be a current flow across |A'B'| as well. The text claims this is due to the fact that the magnetic field **h** without changing its direction will be displaced in the radial direction **M** perpendicular to h.

I couldn't get which law it is talking about in electromagnetic theory. What does the text mean here?

Comment: that's induction. Maybe you're looking for *Faraday's law of induction*? Maybe you're a Electrical Engineering student and will need to know the whole picture sooner or later – then read up on Maxwell's equations.

Comment: The electromagnetic field intensity h at point P increases/varies. This variation in vector h at point P creates an electric force f at that point. This is a point to point explanation. Faraday's law of induction is talking about change in flux creates an emf and I understand that. But I think this must be some part of Maxwell's equations but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Effectively, Faraday's Law is *one* of Maxwell's equations, and they all interweave, so it's **always** the whole of Maxwell's equations. But, again, you really just pluck things in to the one part that most EM theory books (e.g. Pozar's *Microwave Engineering*) just call Faraday's Law of Induction. No magic involved.

Comment: You are right one of the Maxwell's equations which is Faraday's law states that a changing magnetic field has an E-field curling around it. This illustration seems related:https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-79a194d7db7d17b596a5006192031c00-c But when it is a single point and single magnetic field vector it is hard to imagine the curl of this vector.

Comment: well, you got to work on that. It's just a single point from the field that you're considering now.

Comment: Unless of course you are more modern and believe magnetism is not actually a thing and everything has to do with electrostatic forces and relativity. But let's not go there.... The Maxwell et. al. equations work just fine.

Comment: @Trevor The book Im reading is a bit old from 1919. It explains many concepts with fields  inside ether, and no relativity mentioned.

Comment: Yup, just go with the classics for now. It's readily understood by pretty much every EE out there. The new stuff is interesting, but changes nothing since the classic model fits the evidentiary behaviour almost perfectly. I just added the comment for completeness.